# Facebook SDK "Edit Settings" errors in Unity for Android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm currently developing an Android game with Unity using the Facebook SDK.

What I should be able to is open an inspector window titled "Edit Settings" and change properties in the dropdown menu "Android Build Facebook Settings".

What happens to me is this:

http://www.i.imgur.com/L9SOJZl.png

My dropdown menu is totally blank and the console is spammed with the same error repeatedly.

- I have the latest version (non-beta) of the Facebook SDK downloaded and installed correctly.
- The latest version of Unity 4.3.4f1
- I have the Android SDK installed and I can build successfully to a device.
- I have the Java Runtime Environment and Development Kit installed.
- ^^^ Tried both 32bit and 64bit
- I have my Environment Variable "PATH" pointing to the JDK install directory.
- I have installed 32 and 64 bit OpenSSL and still had no success.

The full error code is as follows.

> Win32Exception: ApplicationName='cmd', CommandLine='/Cecho "xxx" | openssl base64', CurrentDirectory=''
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
>   UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.FacebookAndroidUtil.DoesCommandExist (System.String command) (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:134)
>   UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.FacebookAndroidUtil.get_DebugKeyHash () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:41)
>   UnityEditor.FacebookEditor.FacebookAndroidUtil.IsSetupProperly () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:22)
>   FacebookSettingsEditor.AndroidUtilGUI () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs:142)
>   FacebookSettingsEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at Assets/Facebook/Editor/FacebookSettingsEditor.cs:42)
>   UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditors (Boolean isRepaintEvent, UnityEditor.Editor[] editors, Boolean eyeDropperDirty) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:850)
>   UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am also having same error, exactly same. I searched this error and found that it is coming because some of the environment variables got missed/deleted, but if we all are having exactly same problem then it is not due to environment variable. I think may be there is some problem with Facebook unity sdk.

Comment: A question over on UnityAnswers pointed towards environment variables:

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

and
ClassPath - .;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip

These appear to be correct and have no affect on the issue.

Comment: OpenSSL has been installed with no success.
I'm reporting it as a bug now.

Answer (score 4):

I Solved Adding in Enviroment variable "C:\Windows\System32" example:

Path = C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\OpenSSL\bin

Answer (score 0):

**I've solved** creating a .bat file like this:

```
SET PATH=<path-to-openssl>;<path-to-jdk>\bin
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe"
```

It seems to be a problem of ENV VARS not properly read from Unity
NOTE: i'm under Unity 4.3.4f1

Comment: Unfortunately no luck :(
I've ran the BAT file and seen no change in the ENV vars.
I've also edited the vars to be the same as would be output by the .bat.

Sadly neither worked.