# How to fin Win32Exception Error when adding Facebook SDK to Unity?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.0

After adding the Facebook SDK into Unity I am getting this error and the Android Build Facebook Settings arent showing a dropdown.

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='cmd', CommandLine='/Cecho "xxx" | openssl base64', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= The system cannot find the file specified.

System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at <3845a180c26b4889bc2d47593a665814>:0)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at <3845a180c26b4889bc2d47593a665814>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookAndroidUtil.DoesCommandExist (System.String command) (at <1e648b4081db4625b06f95d668cd2dd4>:0)
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookAndroidUtil.get_DebugKeyHash () (at <1e648b4081db4625b06f95d668cd2dd4>:0)
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookAndroidUtil.get_SetupProperly () (at <1e648b4081db4625b06f95d668cd2dd4>:0)
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookSettingsEditor.AndroidUtilGUI () (at <1e648b4081db4625b06f95d668cd2dd4>:0)
Facebook.Unity.Editor.FacebookSettingsEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at <1e648b4081db4625b06f95d668cd2dd4>:0)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DoOnInspectorGUI (System.Boolean rebuildOptimizedGUIBlock, UnityEditor.Editor editor, System.Boolean wasVisible, UnityEngine.Rect& contentRect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1625)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 0):

install openSSL https://www.openssl.org/

I Solved Adding in Enviroment variable "C:\Windows\System32" example:

Path = C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\OpenSSL\bin

**be sure to add them in the exact order**

ref : "[Facebook SDK "Edit Settings" errors in Unity for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806745/facebook-sdk-edit-settings-errors-in-unity-for-android)"